# How can you use a foreach loop that loops for every character in a string? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I need to "Add an element at the end of the array containing the character "%" (percent sign) repeated once for each character in the first element".

```
$input = "0958192,Wherewithal,Eloquence,Panacea,42.10,5915"
```

I tried exploding the array to isolate the first element, but I'm not familiar with looping based on the number of characters when there is not a separator. Any input would be much appreciated

Comment: I think it would be better if you can provide the expected output from that input

Comment: seven "%" at the end of the array in it's own element, not hard coded

Comment: That is why I was exploding it. Thanks for all the help cool guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to count the characters?

```
$input = "0958192,Wherewithal,Eloquence,Panacea,42.10,5915";
$elements = explode(',', $input);
$count = strlen($elements[0]);
```

Comment: Entirely forgot about the strlen function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you extract the first element, explode THAT using an empty string as a delimiter to get an array of single characters.  Loop over that array.